# Accidentally clicked a link which might have been malicious. What should I do?

Tags: virus, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

The link came as spam, so I expect only bad things from it.
I quickly closed the tab before it fully loaded so I don't know what was on the site.
What is the worst that can happen now? If there was some script on that website it might have executed.

What can I do to help the situation now?

Comment: as a side note, links are never malicious. Web pages are, and people are, but links are the victims in all this and i defend their good name.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Comment: Is it possible that I get infected by virus or malware just by visiting a website?

Comment: Yes, although more usually malware. esp if you run out of date software.

Comment: Yes, you can. Check out this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/can-you-get-virus-just-by-visiting-a-website-in-chrome